# Self updating Excel/VBA dashboard, cycling through graphs

Tags: vba, excel

I have a little wall mounted PC with office installed and screen which should display a couple of graphs which are cycled through and refreshed in 5 minute intervals.

In the same folder I created a spreadsheet running on a server into which Reuters dumps data every day, and the "Dashboard" spreadsheet.

I linked a sheet in the Dashboard to the Data import workbook to synchronise data and ran the following VBA code.

```
Sub UpdateEverything()

    startTime = Now
    Workbooks("Dashboard").RefreshAll
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"), "UpdateEverything"
    Debug.Print "I'm still running at " & Now & " and I started at " & startTime

End Sub
```

Questions:
- Is there a better method.

- How to cycle through the sheets containing the full screen graphs?
- How can I show graphs truly full screen, not just a maximised excel window

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, that's a bit smoother but maybe not the greatest.

- It doesn't allow for a smooth interruption of the loop.
- it's sometimes a bit slow updating

---

```
Sub UpdateEverything()

    'sets the start and wait time
    startTime = Now
    updateTime = "00:00:10"
    l = 0

    Do While True
        'update counter
        l = l + 1

        'refresh
        Workbooks("Dashboard").RefreshAll
        Debug.Print "I was still running at " & Now & " and I started at " & startTime
        Debug.Print "loop #" & l & " and i #" & i

        For Each c In Charts

            'show next graph
            c.Activate
            'wait a bit
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue(updateTime)

        Next

    Loop

End Sub
```